# What determines whether a JDialog closes when the main JFrame does?

Tags: java, swing, jvm, window, jdialog

I don't think this is a duplicate.

My app at the current time has a main JFrame.  Various JDialogs are created setting it as the owner.
When I close the JFrame, having done `setDefaultCloseOperation()` to `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, the JDialogs created from JOptionPanes, which are just hidden when not in use, do not prevent the JVM from shutting down.

But I have just introduced a JDialog subclass where again the owner is the JFrame, and again, when not in use, I am just setting this JDialog to visible = False.  But when I close the JFrame this appears to persist, preventing the JVM from shutting down.

I thought it might be something to do with the modality, so set this to `APPLICATION_MODAL`.  But no.

There are workarounds of course: a `WindowListener.windowClosing` on the JFrame, and "dispose" for the JDialog I'm talking about.  But I'd prefer to set it so that it closes down automatically like the other JDialogs do...

Comment: When you created the JDialog, did you give it a non-null parent window (i.e, your JFrame)?

Comment: yes, as I said in the post

Comment: Works fine for me. That is the JVM will exit even if the dialog is not visible when the frame is closed. Maybe a version/platform issue. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem so people can test your code.

Comment: thanks... I'll make one.